# Inserting Column By Grouping Values in different column with Commas

Tags: r, dplyr, paste

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
COL1     COL2 
Dest1    SMALL
Dest1    MED
Dest2    SMALL
Dest3    LARGE
```

I want convert it to this:

```
COL1     COL2        COL3
Dest1    SMALL    SMALL, MED
Dest1    MED      SMALL, MED
Dest2    SMALL       SMALL
Dest3    LARGE       LARGE
```

I tried something like this but I don't know how to get the comma in there.

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df %>% group_by(COL1) %>% mutate(COL3 = paste(COL2))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind I figured it out:

```
df2<-df %>% group_by(COL1) %>% mutate(COL3=paste(COL2, sep="", collapse=","))
```

Comment: There's a function for that `df %>% group_by(COL1) %>% mutate(COL3=toString(COL2))`

Comment: By the way, you might want to `sort` and `unique` COL2 before pasting, depending on why you're doing it.

Comment: @Frank yes I ended up taking the unique values in the end. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is an another option using base function

```
aggregate(data = df,COL2~COL1,FUN = paste)
```